# PHP - how can I stop a function from printing an extra || at the end?

Tags: php, javascript

In PHP I have a function, the problem is it will output an extra || at the end that I dont want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide_card_code() {
  var payment_source=document.getElementById('payment_source');
  if(
    <?
    forEach($result_cards as $key => $value) {
      echo "payment_source.value=='$value' || \n";
    }
    ?>
    ) {
    //do stuff...
    return true;
  }
}
</script>
```

It will output the following HTML.  Note the extra || at the end.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide_card_code() {
  var payment_source=document.getElementById('payment_source');
  if(
    payment_source.value=='23' || 
    payment_source.value=='24' || 
    payment_source.value=='25' || 
    ) {
    //do stuff...
    return true;
  }
}
</script>
```

How do I stop that extra || ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for a loop! Just use `json_encode` to make a JavaScript array out of the values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide_card_code() {
    var payment_source = document.getElementById('payment_source');

    if(<?= json_encode(array_values($result_cards)) ?>.indexOf(payment_source.value) > -1) {
        // do stuff...
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $i=0;
 forEach($result_cards as $key => $value) {
   if($i == 0){
     echo "payment_source.value=='$value' \n";
     $i++;
   }
   else
     echo " || payment_source.value=='$value' \n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why make things complicated, if there is a simple way? `json_encode` is slow, looping is silly: why not string the array like so:

```
echo 'payment_source.value=="'.implode('" || payment_source.value=="',array_values($array)).'"';
```

echo's: `payment_source.value=="[val1]" || payment_source.value=="[val2]" || payment_source.value=="[val3]"`

regardless of the number size of the array. Do keep the closing `.'"'` bit in mind...

Comment: I was going to post this (or a variant of it) but I figured `json_encode` would be simpler. If it's a performance bottleneck, there's something seriously wrong :)

Comment: True, the performance diff. would be less than the weight of an electron. Though, your solution implicitly calls the `Array` constructor on each call to the `hide_card_code` function, by not storing it in a variable first. That's just one of those things I'd never want to do, but then I have been accused of OCD when it comes to stuff like that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Accumulate everything into a string before echoing it, then use rtrim(), then echo it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide_card_code() {
  var payment_source=document.getElementById('payment_source');
  if(<?
      echo 'payment_source.value==' , 
      implode(' || payment_source.value==', $result_cards);
  ?>) {
    //do stuff...
    return true;
  }
}
```